# How to get what exist in the first datatable and not exist in the second data table in a third one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

Q:

I have two queries each one return a `DataTable`. I wanna to return another `DaTaTable` as a result of(**What exist in the first DataTable AND Not Exist(NOT IN) the second DataTable**).

My queries:

**EDIT : I make it general:**

1-DT1:

```
DataTable dt1 = cc1assiscrsevalDAL.GetAll(int.Parse(Session["course_prof"].ToString()), 0);
```

2-DT2:

```
DataTable dt2 = cc1assiscrsevalDAL.GetConfirmedEval(int.Parse(Session["course_prof"].ToString()));
```

> Note:batch_no,crsnum,lect_code are the composite primary key

---

What is the best way to do that?(wise performance).
I wanna also to do that with LINQ.(if possible).

Comment: Anytime you use NOT EXISTS you're setting yourself up for a performance hit, depending on the size of the table, because NOT EXISTS will do a complete table scan.

Comment: @Tim: can you prove that in any way? This says NOT EXISTS *is* optimised becauses it's a semi-join http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/the-use-of-not-logic-in-relation-to-indexes/4010#4010 or here where it's explored for MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle: http://explainextended.com/

Comment: @gbn - I based that on what numerous DBAs I've worked with in the past have told me.  Apparently it's not completely true (like many other blanket statements). I still think, however, that it's best to avoid NOT EXISTS when you can.

Comment: @just_name: What tables are EXISTS and NOT EXISTS?

Comment: @Tim: You think what you want: but don't post rubbish like this on public forums...

Comment: @gbn - I posted what I thought and felt was true from my experience - I didn't say it was the gospel truth.  If I'm wrong, I'm wrong - we're all human.  When I have time (which I don't right now) I'll look at the links in detail that you posted and see if my opinion needs revising.

Comment: @Tim: this myth pops up time and time again all over the interwebs, and here on SO. It's important to note that `NOT EXISTS` (or `NOT IN`) is actually a kind of JOIN. It isn't like `NOT (x=2)` which of course is non SARGable

Comment: @gbn - points noted, thanks for the clarification.  I'll read up on your links more tomorrow.

Comment: I want the the first datatable records which not exist in the second data table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dt = dt1.AsEnumerable().Except(dt2.AsEnumerable(), new CustomDataRowEqualityComparer()).CopyToDataTable();

    public class CustomDataRowEqualityComparer: IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
        {

            public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
            {
                return ((int)x["crsnum"]) == ((int)y["crsnum"])
                    && ((int)x["crsnum_e"]) == ((int)y["crsnum_e"])
                        && ((int)x["crstteng"]) == ((int)y["crstteng"]);
            }

            public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
            {
                return ((int)obj["crsnum"]) ^ ((int)obj["crsnum_e"]) ^ ((int)obj["crstteng"]) ;
            }
        }
```

There is an extension method in the linq called Except which solves your problem but we need to create a separate class for that which i have done in the above code.

Comment: That will result in all records that ARE in both queries, but just_name needs not to include records that are in second query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from (*target_query*) t
join
(
  select batch_no,crsnum,lect_code from (*target_query*) q
  except
  select batch_no,crsnum,lect_code from cc1assiscrseval
) temp on temp.batch_no = t.batch_no and temp.lect_code = t.lect_code, temp.crsnum = t.crsnum
```

Pretty dirty solution, but I think you could simplify it by getting only desired batch_no, crsnum and lect_code, without performing first query twice. But you'll have to figure it out yourself.

Comment: Still different structure. What keys do you want to include/exclude? I'm not aware of your db structure :)

Answer (score 0):

Linq provides you with an Except method so you could do something like this

```
var _differences = dt1.AsEnumerable.Except(dt2.AsEnumerable()); // No checked or tested in VS
```

You could also first get the relevant columns by using something like this:

```
var x = From a In dt1
    Select (...relevant columns)

var y = From a In dt2
    Select (...relevant columns)
```

And then do the above except.

HTH!